# Htaccess removing .html

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

This is code from my .htaccess file

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options -Indexes

# blocks direct access to the XML files - they hold all the data!
<Files ~ "\.xml$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</Files>
<Files sitemap.xml>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Satisfy All
</Files>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# Usually it RewriteBase is just '/', but 
# replace it with your subdirectory path
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Most of it was previously generated not by me, and that's may be the problem i cannot understand it. I wanted to remove .html from mywebsite.co.uk/promotions.html.
I have tried adding, deleting lines and searched for answers for a long time and i still get nothing. Everything i get is sth like: mywebsite.co.uk/?id=promotions which is even worse. Actually i am newbie with htaccess and most of this code is more or less magic for me. I would be happy to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this

```
RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/$ /$1.html
```

Comment: You mean delete this:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
and use your formula? Now i have 500 internal server error

Comment: Both ways should work sorry, have you checked your server configuration?

Just to see if Apache is on and it is viewable?

Comment: Actually i don't have permission to this server. Well, thank you, i thought i can change it myself but if you said it's server configuration i need to stop wasting my time on this task.